# IList<T> crashes when T is an event handler?

Tags: delphi, spring4d

It appears to me that IList can NOT take Event handler as its element.  The program has access violation $C00000005 on PROGRAM exit.

Everything is fine if I use Delphi RTL's TList.

The access violation happens for both 32 bit and 64bit build. When it happens, it seems to halt at the following lines of Spring4D:

```
procedure TCollectionBase<T>.Changed(const item: T; action:      
   TCollectionChangedAction);
begin
   if fOnChanged.CanInvoke then
       fOnChanged.Invoke(Self, item, action);
end;
```

The following sample program can replicate the access violation, using RAD Studio Tokyo 10.2.3, on Windows.

```
program Test_Spring_IList_With_Event_Handler;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Spring.Collections;

type
  TSomeEvent = procedure of object;

  TMyEventHandlerClass = class
    procedure SomeProcedure;
  end;

  TMyClass = class
  private
    FEventList: IList<TSomeEvent>;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure AddEvent(aEvent: TSomeEvent);
  end;

procedure TMyEventHandlerClass.SomeProcedure;
begin
  // Nothing to do.
end;

constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FEventList := TCollections.CreateList<TSomeEvent>;
end;

destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
begin
  FEventList := nil;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyClass.AddEvent(aEvent: TSomeEvent);
begin
  FEventList.Add(aEvent);
end;

var
  MyEventHandlerObj: TMyEventHandlerClass;
  MyObj: TMyClass;
begin
  MyObj := TMyClass.Create;
  MyEventHandlerObj := TMyEventHandlerClass.Create;

  try
    MyObj.AddEvent(MyEventHandlerObj.SomeProcedure);
  finally
    MyObj.Free;
    MyEventHandlerObj.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: An event handler consists of a method and an instance. If you destroy the instance the event handler is not valid anymore.

Comment: Event types (procedure of object) are treated specially - they have two pointers actually. The compiler does a bit of magic behind the scenes with them.

Comment: Note that the code as shown should only crash if it is not running on an ARC-based platform, and `TSomeClass.SomeProcedure()` actually does something with its `Self` parameter.

Comment: Cannot reproduce and I am confident that there is no defect in this part of spring. Please provide [mcve]. Much more likely is that your actual code calls the method stored in the list after you have freed the object.

Comment: With the code above (plus an empty impl of the method) I get an AV from `System.UnsetExceptionHandler` during the finalization of the program (in Delphi 10.2.2 - not updated to release 3 on my notebook yet) - I expect some defect in the RTL rather than in Spring4D though. Should not be closed and I will investigate.

Comment: Thank you all for the heads up.  Some additional information when the crash happened to me: 1).  Tokyo 10.2.3,  Windows Server 2102;  2). The object (that the event handler belongs to) is still live (i.e., not destroyed yet),  when the access violation happens

Comment: Er, how can that be. You called free on it. A [MCVE] would help so that we can be 100% sure we are looking at the same problem. Also, please let us know what the error message is. Such details are important. Edit the question to include version and os information also.

Comment: Hi @DavidHeffernan, I updated the problem statement. Thank you.

Comment: Great. That's much better. I have the answer. It's a compiler bug. I have a workaround in the spring code. I'm going to commit a fix on my fork and @Stefan will merge it into the main repo on the 1.2.2 branch. Just give me a few minutes to write the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a compiler defect that impacts generics. The lifetime of the `TMyClass` instance isn't actually relevant. The code that the compiler can't handle is in `TList<T>.DeleteRangeInternal` in `Spring.Collections.Lists`. This code:

```
if doClear then
  Changed(Default(T), caReseted);
```

Remember that `T` is a method pointer, that is a type with two pointers. As such it is larger than a register. The compiler turns the call to `Changed` into this:

```
Spring.Collections.Lists.pas.641: Changed(Default(T), caReseted);
00504727 B105             mov cl,$05
00504729 33D2             xor edx,edx
0050472B 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
0050472E 8B18             mov ebx,[eax]
00504730 FF5374           call dword ptr [ebx+$74]
```

Notice that the compiler only zeroises 4 bytes, and then passes those four bytes to `Changed`.

However, on the other side of this is the implementation of `Changed`, whose code to access the `item` which it passed looks like this:

```
Spring.Collections.Base.pas.1583: fOnChanged.Invoke(Self, item, action);
00502E58 FF750C           push dword ptr [ebp+$0c]
00502E5B FF7508           push dword ptr [ebp+$08]
00502E5E 8D55F0           lea edx,[ebp-$10]
00502E61 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
00502E64 8B4024           mov eax,[eax+$24]
00502E67 8B08             mov ecx,[eax]
00502E69 FF513C           call dword ptr [ecx+$3c]
```

The first two lines of asm code there read the method pointer from the stack. So the ABI for method pointer parameters is that they are passed on the stack. This is documented as follows:

> A method pointer is passed on the stack as two 32-bit pointers. The instance pointer is pushed before the method pointer so that the method pointer occupies the lowest address.

Back to the code that called this function. It passed the argument in a register. That mismatch is the cause of the exception which actually happens much later on. But this is where everything goes south.

Let's look at a workaround. We change the code in `TList<T>.DeleteRangeInternal` to be like so:

```
var
  defaultItem: T;
....
if doClear then
begin
  defaultItem := Default(T);
  Changed(defaultItem, caReseted);
end;
```

Now the generated code is this:

```
Spring.Collections.Lists.pas.643: defaultItem := Default(T);
0050472B 33C0             xor eax,eax
0050472D 8945E0           mov [ebp-$20],eax
00504730 8945E4           mov [ebp-$1c],eax
Spring.Collections.Lists.pas.644: Changed(defaultItem, caReseted);
00504733 FF75E4           push dword ptr [ebp-$1c]
00504736 FF75E0           push dword ptr [ebp-$20]
00504739 B205             mov dl,$05
0050473B 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
0050473E 8B08             mov ecx,[eax]
00504740 FF5174           call dword ptr [ecx+$74]
```

Note that this time code is generated to zeroise both pointers in the method pointer and then pass them via the stack. This calling code matches the callee's code. And all is well.

I will submit this workaround to my personal Spring4D repo and Stefan will merge it into the 1.2.2 hotfix branch on the main repo.

I submitted a bug report: [RSP-20683](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20683).

Comment: Do you maybe have an array of Delphi versions to check the workaround to your workaround, until it screwed some yet another compiler? :-D For future reference, the secondary problem at https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d/issues/338